# Wordpress when sending a WP_Ajax_Response the response is not received

Tags: ajax, wordpress, response

I'm searching for days now for a solution to my problem.
When I send a WP_Ajax_Response the clientside is not receiving it.
I checked all possible tips on internet but still I can't get it working.
Can somebody help me?

I registered the javascript file:

```
wp_register_script('test-ajax-js',get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/script/ajax.test.js', array( 'jquery', 'wp-ajax-response' ), '1.0' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'test-ajax-js');
wp_localize_script( 'test-ajax-js', 'ajaxtest', 
                    array( 
                        'Ajax_Url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                        'deshopNonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'deshop-ajax-test-nonce' )
                    ) 
            );
```

This is the PHP code:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_shop_ajax_test', 'test_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_shop_ajax_test', 'test_function');

function test_function() {
check_ajax_referer( 'deshop-ajax-test-nonce' );


$response = array( 'what'=>'validate_user_login',
            'action'=>'validate_user_login_results',
            'id'=>'1',
            'data'=>'OK' 
            );

$xmlResponse = new WP_Ajax_Response($response);
$xmlResponse->send();

exit();
}
```

and this is the javascript file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(event) {
var post = {
                action: 'shop_ajax_test',
                _ajax_nonce: ajaxtest.deshopNonce
            };

jQuery.post( ajaxtest.Ajax_Url, post, function(response){
                var res = wpAjax.parseAjaxResponse(response, 'ajax-response');
                jQuery.each( res.responses, function() {
                    var a = 0;
                });
            });

});
```

While debugging the res content shows responses=[0]. In the jQuery.each function no responses are handled!

Thanks a lot for any tips that might help me out here!

Marc

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem but I solved it by using jQuery.ajax() not post()
here's a link that might

Answer (score 0):

Is it at all possible that the domain, subdomain, or protocol are different?  That will kill an Ajax response as the browser won't send it.

Also, have you used Firefox's firebug or Chrome's inspector, as apparently they will show you the request and the response (or perhaps why it didn't get there)?